# Moving bootstrap div tag

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using bootstrap. I want a div element to move as I scroll the page downwards. How do I accomplish this please? For instance, I want the div element to follow me downwards as I scroll downwards and still maintain its position

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can accomplished with functionality jQuery plugin.

See more on the API call [here](http://bigspotteddog.github.io/ScrollToFixed/)

This jQuery plugin is used to fix elements on the page (top, bottom, anywhere); however, it still allows the element to continue to move left or right with the horizontal scroll.

Given an option marginTop, the element will stop moving vertically upward once the vertical scroll has reached the target position; but, the element will still move horizontally as the page is scrolled left or right. Once the page has been scrolled back down past the target position, the element will be restored to its original position on the page.

Answer (score 0):

Using CSS, you can do it with the `position` attribute.

```
div{
    position: fixed;
}
```